# Why is Dictionary.First() so slow?

Tags: .net, performance, algorithm, hashtable

Not a real question because I already found out the answer, but still interesting thing.

I always thought that hash table is the fastest associative container if you hash properly.

However, the following code is terribly slow. It executes only about 1 million iterations and takes more than 2 minutes of time on a Core 2 CPU.

The code does the following: it maintains the collection `todo` of items it needs to process. At each iteration it takes an item from this collection (doesn't matter which item), deletes it, processes it if it wasn't processed (possibly adding more items to process), and repeats this until there are no items to process.

The culprit seems to be the Dictionary.Keys.First() operation.

The question is why is it slow?

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();

HashSet<int> processed = new HashSet<int>();
Dictionary<int, int> todo = new Dictionary<int, int>();

todo.Add(1, 1);
int iterations = 0;

int limit = 500000;
while (todo.Count > 0)
{
    iterations++;
    var key = todo.Keys.First();
    var value = todo[key];
    todo.Remove(key);
    if (!processed.Contains(key))
    {
        processed.Add(key);
        // process item here
        if (key < limit) { todo[key + 13] = value + 1; todo[key + 7] = value + 1; }
        // doesn't matter much how
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Iterations: {0}; Time: {1}.", iterations, watch.Elapsed);
```

This results in:

```
Iterations: 923007; Time: 00:02:09.8414388.
```

Simply changing Dictionary to SortedDictionary yields:

```
Iterations: 499976; Time: 00:00:00.4451514.
```

300 times faster while having only 2 times less iterations.

The same happens in java.
Used `HashMap` instead of `Dictionary` and `keySet().iterator().next()` instead of `Keys.First()`.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: it is tagged as both java and .net, and in his last sentence OP says "The same happens in java"

Comment: The real question is , what does First returns? Since Dictionnary uses hash values, First is first of what???

Comment: First() returns the first item that would be returned if you enumerated through the dictionary. This order is not defined, sou you just get "an item".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` maintains a hash table.

Its enumerator will loop through the buckets in the hash table until it finds a non-empty bucket, then return the value in that bucket.
Once the dictionary grows large, this operation becomes expensive.
In addition, removing an item from the dictionary doesn't shrink the buckets array, so the `First()` call gets *slower* as you remove items.  (Because it has to loop further to find a non-empty bucket)

Therefore, repeatedly calling `First()` and removing is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

---

By the way, you can avoid the value lookup like this: (This will not make it noticeably faster)

```
var kvp = todo.First();

//Use kvp.Key and kcp.Value
```

Comment: Yes, your explanation is correct and complete.
By the way, Microsoft documentation says that GetEnumerator() operation is O(1) for Dictionary. Yet it doesn't say anything about the enumerator's MoveNext() performance. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Dictionary makes no effort to keep track of a list of keys.  So the iterator needs to walk the buckets.  Many of these buckets, particularly for a large dictionary, many not have anything in them.

It may be helpful to compare OpenJDK's [HashIterator.nextEntry](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/icedtea/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) and [PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/icedtea/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/TreeMap.java) (which uses TreeMap.successor).  The hash version walks an unknown number of entries looking for one that's non-null.  This could be particularly slow if the hash table has had many elements removed (which it has in your case).  In TreeMap, the only walking we do is our in-order traversal.  There are no nulls in the way (only at the leaves).

Comment: The amortized time per item returned, though, ought to be about the same regardless of the size of the dictionary.

Comment: @Nick: No, it isn't.  See my answer.

Comment: Modulo the edge case of removing items - which sounds like a weakness of .net's implementation - the proportion of filled buckets should be the same regardless of the size.

Comment: @Nick, Not just .NET's implementation. Java suffers too. C++ STL doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Reflector shows that `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` maintains a `Entry<TKey, TValue>` array that it's `KeyCollection<TKey, TValue>.Enumerator<TKey, TValue>` uses. Normally, the lookup should be relatively fast, as it can just index into the array (assuming you don't want a sorted `First`):

```
// Dictionary<TKey. TValue>
private Entry<TKey, TValue>[] entries;
```

*However*, if you're removing the first elements of that array, then you end up walking the array until you find a non-empty one:

```
// Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection<TKey, TValue>.Enumerator<TKey, TValue>
while (this.index < this.dictionary.count) {
    if (this.dictionary.entries[this.index].hashCode >= 0) {
        this.currentKey = this.dictionary.entries[this.index].key;
        this.index++;
        return true;
    }
    this.index++;
}
```

As you remove your entries, you start getting more and more empties at the front of the `entries` array, and it becomes slower to retrieve `First` next time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Hash Tables aren't sorted, my guess is it it has to do some sort of sort before it can do an iteration, or some sort of scan, if its already sorted, it can just loop through.

Comment: Although, I believe Dictionary is a Tree in the back end.

Comment: .Net's `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` uses a hash table.

Comment: Also, a remove on a tree could be kind of expensive.

Answer (score -1):

Without looking, the simplest implementation of a sorted dictionary is a sorted list (like TreeSet) of keys and a hash combined; the list gives you the ordering, the dictionary gives you values. Thus the keys are already available. Hashtable does not have keys readily available, thus the culprit is not `first`, it's `keys` (all without any shred of evidence, feel free to test the hypothesis ;D )

Comment: .Net's `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` uses a hash table.

Comment: Probably. I was speaking in general (using hashtable and dictionary interchangeably) - it should be applicable to any paradigm. In .net, specifically, they make a difference between the two in type enforcement, but it does not make any difference to the question at hand - the structure of data is same.