# ternary operator imbrication

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, conditional-operator

I am wondering: what is the best instruction in terms of performance between those 2 versions:

```
Background = Application.Current.Resources[condition ? BackgroundName1 : BackgroundName2] as Brush;
```

and:

```
Background = condition ? Application.Current.Resources[BackgroundName1] as Brush : Application.Current.Resources[BackgroundName2] as Brush;
```

is there any difference? and if yes, which one is better?

NB: BackgroundName1 & 2 are simply strings

Comment: Have you looked at the IL? The first is easier to read which outweighs all other concerns but "Does it work?" IMHO.

Comment: Use whatever is easier for you to read and to maintain.

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you have a performance problem, that isn't going to be the line of code that causes it; if you don't have a problem, worrying about this is premature optimization.

Comment: @michael: I do have performance issues and I was looking everywhere I could to try to gain some time here and there... I admit I must have hit a milestone though... I'm probably not going to be able to gain much more... Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one is shorter and more readable.

It's also easier to maintain.
If you later change it to read a different Resources dictionary, you might forget to change the second half of the second one.

The first one is also more clearly reading from the same dictionary.

Comment: thanks. I do have performance issue, though I was not really convinced of the necessity to have to tweak that line, but just out of curiosity...

Answer (score 3):

First: Use a profiler to find the slowest thing. If you're having a performance problem it doesn't make sense to spend hours or days working on making something faster that is already fast enough.

Second: You can determine the answer to your question by trying it both ways and carefully measuring to see if there is a difference. Don't ask us which is faster; we don't know because we haven't tried it and have no ability to try it.

Comment: Actually, I'm reasonably certain that they will perform _identically_.  Both cases perform one cast, dictionary lookup, and property getter.  Unless he has evil side effects, there will be no difference at all.

Comment: @SLaks: I'm pretty sure you're right. As my old dev manager used to say "are you sure enough that you'd bet your car on it?" If I've learned one thing over the years about performance, it's that sometimes performance of a complex system is deeply counterintuitive. For example, we recently were tuning a system that was constrained on collection pressure and discovered that when we took away a large number of allocations, the program got *slower*. Those allocations just happened to be aligning some other blocks in just the right way...

Comment: Yes.  [Here's another example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046805/why-is-dictionary-first-so-slow).

Answer (score 2):

Don't get too caught up in micro-optimizations!  The performance gain you'll get will be nil.  Go for the code that is more readable and easier to understand in the end.

Answer (score 0):

No difference whatsoever.