# Why is ReactiveList with ChangeTrackingEnabled slow when I Clear inside SuppressChangeNotifications?

Tags: reactiveui

Why is ReactiveList with ChangeTrackingEnabled slow when I Clear inside SuppressChangeNotifications?

With 10,000 entries it takes about 2 seconds for the Clear method to return.

Shouldn't SuppressChangeNotifications bypass the change tracking code?

Or how can I improve the performance here?

```
ReactiveList<Person> _personList = new ReactiveList<Person> { ChangeTrackingEnabled = true };


            using (_personList.SuppressChangeNotifications())
            {
                _personList.Clear();
            }
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change tracking code is bypassed, but still ReactiveList needs to cleanup its internal stuff when you clear the list. And the [method used](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI/ReactiveList.cs#L675) to do so is extremely inefficient ( `O(n2)` ), as detailed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3046838/615903).

The Clear implementation with change tracking enabled can definitely be improved, I'll send a PR to RxUI if I get the chance.

E.g. replacing this code by `foreach (var foo in _propertyChangeWatchers.Values.ToList()) foo.Release();` makes the Clear immediate, w/o altering the behavior.

*EDIT* :

You can work around this performance issue by writing instead:

```
using (_personList.SuppressChangeNotifications())
    _personList.RemoveRange(0, _personList.Count);
```